# Access Denied (SQLEditors)

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an Employee Database in SQL Server 2008. When I right click on any table and chose **Edit Top 200 Rows** then it shows following Error Box:
[image: Access Denied Error]

How can i fix it?
Thanks

Comment: I think you don't have permission. please check in which account the SQL Server service is running.

Answer (score 0):

I think your database requires internet to be connected

1. Open your sql server management studio as administrator
2. Connect your PC to internet then choose Edit

Answer (score 0):

Goto SqlServer Configuration manager, Right click on your server, on build in service, change from network service to local Service